# addFirst method not working properly in a custom linkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

My problem is that when I use this method, and prints out the list after adding som Resepts(Integer), the order of the list is 0,3,2,1 in stead of  3,2,1,0 as I want it to be.

```
public void addFirst(Resept nyResept) {

    Node node = new Node(nyResept);

    if (topNode == null) {
        topNode = node;
        bottomNode = node;
        node.next = null;
        amount++;

    } else {

        node.next = topNode.next;
        topNode.next = node;

        amount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just linking them incorrectly.

Assuming that your new `node` is the new top node, this should not point to the existing `topNode.next` but to `topNode itself.`

Assuming this is your original list:

```
 +------+        +------+       +-------+
 |node 2+------->|node 1+------>| node 0|
 +------+        +------+       +-------+
```

If you want to insert a new node, why would you point it to `node 1` instead of `node 2`?

```
         +------+        +------+       +-------+
  +----+>|node 2+------->|node 1+------>| node 0|
  |      +------+        +------+       +-------+
  |
  |
  |
  |    +-----------+
  ++-++| new node  |
       +-----------+
```

which means that you should have

```
node.next = topnode;
```

Comment: Thank you! Removed next on both. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: @Daniel Nice graphic.

Comment: @BrianVanover thanks! I used http://www.asciiflow.com/ which can be really useful when trying to visualize simple concepts!

Answer (score 1):

Daniel B's answer already shows you what you should be doing. Just for interest's sake, Here's what it's *actually* doing if your list starts with 3 nodes:

Original list:

```
topNode
 v
[node 1]->[node 2]->[node 3]
```

After `node.next = topNode.next;` it looks like this:

```
topNode
 v
[node 1]-------------+->[node 2]->[node 3]
                     |
            [node 4]-+
             ^
            node
```

and then after `topNode.next = node;` it looks like this:

```
topNode
 v
[node 1]-+           +->[node 2]->[node 3]
         |           |
         +->[node 4]-+
             ^
            node
```

or, simplified, like this:

```
topNode   node
 v         v
[node 1]->[node 4]->[node 2]->[node 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work properly because your else clause does **NOT** insert new node but does something else.
Read your code again and see what is wrong...

Notes:
There is no difference in processing empty and non-empty list...

Comment: Seems like he's interting the new node after top in the else part to me.

Comment: @gla3dr I am really struggling to work out what happens there - I think that else part creates short-circuit list, but I don't have time to think about it too much...

Comment: have a look at my answer to see what is happening.